# Pandas read_csv usecols and names not working properly

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file in pandas without headers. My problem is that when i hard code values in usecols and names it works fine. But when i take input from cols and names list which are taken as input from json files, the column names and rows are mismatched. I'm really struck at this issue from a long time.

//This doesn't work.

```
temp = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None ,
                   skiprows=[0], engine='python',
                   sep=' |,',
                   usecols=cols,
                   names=names)
```

// But this works

```
temp = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None ,
                   skiprows=[0], engine='python',
                   sep=' |,',
                   usecols=[10,12,14],
                   names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Consider this csv :

```
X-Y-Z,12.67,India,
A-X-o,11.43,China,
D-F-L,6.09,Kenya.
```

Now running this code

```
cols = [2,3,1]
names = ['price','country','code']

temp = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None ,
                   skiprows=[0], engine='python',
                   sep=' |,',
                   usecols = cols,
                   names= names)
```

produces...

```
   price  country   code
0  A-X-o    11.43  China
1  D-F-L     6.09  Kenya
```

which is wrong as country's are not decimals

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['a', 'b','c']
#always use `skipinitialspace` which remove the spaces in the header for reading specific columns
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
```

EDIT:

You are doing it in a wrong way usecols as `[2,3,1]` and `[1,2,3]` both are same it is not going to change the order,what matters is how you specify `names`

```
import pandas as pd   

df = {'letters': ['X-Y-Z','A-X-o','D-F-L'],
    'num': [12.67,11.43,6.09],
    'Country':['India','China','Kenya']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.to_csv('df.csv', header=False)
```

Let's consider some scenario

```
#this is what you have done
cols = [2,3,1]
names = ['price','country','code']
temp = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=None ,skiprows=[0], engine='python', sep=',',usecols = cols, names= names)
```

OUTPUT

```
        price   country code
   1    A-X-o   11.43   China
   2    D-F-L   6.09    Kenya
```

Lets change the cols to `[1,2,3]` and there will be no change in output

```
cols = [1,2,3]
names = ['price','country','code']
temp = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=None ,skiprows=[0], engine='python', sep=',',usecols = cols, names= names)
```

OUTPUT

```
        price   country code
   1    A-X-o   11.43   China
   2    D-F-L   6.09    Kenya
```

Now lets change the `cols` to `[2,3,1]` or `[1,2,3]` and `names` to `['code','price','country']`

```
cols = [2,3,1]
names = ['code','price','country']
temp = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=None ,skiprows=[0], engine='python', sep=',', usecols = cols, names= names)
```

OUTPUT

```
    code    price   country
0   A-X-o   11.43   China
1   D-F-L   6.09    Kenya
```

So basically just switching the cols to [2,3,1] and assigning its names  accordingly as ['price','country','code'] will not give you different results, because `usecols[2,3,1]` == `usecols[1,2,3]`

Comment: It's still mismatching columns and assigning wrong column names

Comment: The df is huge but the csv don't have column names so I have to assign it column names. So when i give uscols=[1,2] and names=['a','b'] it works but not with usecols = cols and names = names

Comment: above code should work fine,provide something to work with or provide the `cols` that you are passing to `usecols`

Comment: Provided it in question description now

Comment: @CrazyGuy pl accept the answer if it helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

use simply file name with the location it will work [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
temp = pd.read_csv(file_name,usecols= ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

on therhand you could pull all the columns csv file and drop the un used column like below

```
temp=pd.read_csv(file_name)

temp.drop(['col1','col2'...'coln'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I want to read only particular columns not the whole csv file as file is too large and csv file has no columns name so I have to assign them

Comment: @CrazyGuy then add column names

Comment: @CrazyGuy it would be usecols parameter

Comment: No you are not understanding the problem, it's picking all columns i want but it's assigning wrong column names, So when I retrieve data using column name i get wrong data

Comment: @CrazyGuy you could check columns name by using temp.columns then copy your necessary column and inside usecols list