# Pandas cannot rename columns or insert column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am reading a csv file in python without any prior headers or labels. I would like to add names to my columns and I followed the documentation but there is **no change to the document** I also try to insert a row, but there is also no change to the csv

I am stuck as to why there is no change. See the code below:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=['a', 'b', 'label'])
    bias=[1 for i in range(79)]
    data.insert(0, 'bias', bias)
```

Sources Used:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html and [Pandas read_csv usecols and names not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306049/pandas-read-csv-usecols-and-names-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce. I create a data frame from mock data with the same length.

```
>>> data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join([','.join(['1', '2', 'a'])] * 79)), header=None, names=['a', 'b', 'label'])
    a  b label
0   1  2     a
1   1  2     a
.. .. ..   ...
77  1  2     a
78  1  2     a

[79 rows x 3 columns]
```

`df.insert` operates in place, so I don't need to reassign or anything like that.

```
>>> data.insert(0, 'bias', bias)
>>> data
    bias  a  b label
0      1  1  2     a
1      1  1  2     a
..   ... .. ..   ...
77     1  1  2     a
78     1  1  2     a

[79 rows x 4 columns]
```

But I observe here that the data frame properly reassigns. Could you provide more information?